# Add extra field and value to django query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Hi I am doing a query like

```
user_list = Myuser.objects.filter(status=active)
```

now I want to add a new filed `matching_percentage`  to a user who query it , Like want to show how much it matches to your profile. Now I searched **annotate** function but till now I found that you cant assign a custom calculated value to new filed .

So Is there any way to assign to a filed int values to show how much it matches my profile on run time by a algorithm  ?

**Update**

I am trying something like this

```
query=MyUser.objects.annotate(annotated_field=Value(MyFunction(F('id')), output_field=IntegerField()))\
            .filter(id__in=ids)
```

`F('id')`  is not converting to ID just passing in function as a string

Comment: You need to write *annotate expression* for the *matching_percentage* logic.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  kindly can you show example please ?  as percentage logic is not related to Database fields . would be a great help

Comment: You can see lots of examples in the official doc itself. For instance, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  yes I have check them , they are using database field values . while I want to get value from custom function

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  not getting what you are saying sir :(  . any example would be highly appreciated